# Android don't load fragment (with Activity). Why?

Tags: android

I'm trying to go to a specific fragment and I intialisate this in Activity.  But I don't get any error on my screen but on my device, my app is stopped running, he doesn't go in Fragment. What can be the problem?  Thanx for you help.  Below you find my code:

```
public class SubCatActivity extends Activity {
int hoofdCat;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_subcat);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, new SubCatFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    hoofdCat = Integer.parseInt(getIntent().getStringExtra("hoofdCat"));
}

public int getHoofdCat(){return hoofdCat;}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.info, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

My Fragment:

```
public class SubCatFragment extends Fragment implements SubCatFragmentInteractionListener {

private SubCatFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public SubCatFragment(){

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_subcat, container, false);

    ListView lstSubcat = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.lvSubcat);

    ArrayList<String> subcat = new ArrayList<String>();
    SubCatActivity activity = (SubCatActivity)getActivity();
    int hoofdcat =activity.getHoofdCat();
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(getActivity().getBaseContext());
    db.open();
    Cursor c = db.getAllSubcat(hoofdcat);
    if(c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do{
            subcat.add(c.getString(1));
        }while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    db.close();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, subcat);
    lstSubcat.setAdapter(adapter);

    lstSubcat.setOnItemClickListener(lstSubcatItemClickListener);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mListener = (SubCatFragmentInteractionListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement HoofdCatFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

private ListView.OnItemClickListener lstSubcatItemClickListener = new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        //mListener.showSubCatActivity(pos+1);
    }
};
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use FragmentActivity.

```
public class SubCatActivity extends FragmentActivity{
....
}
```

[FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)

Answer (score 0):

Replace or add the fragment inside onPostCreate, not on onCreate.